# Editing .zshrc to color coat ls output in iterm2 based on file type

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2, zshrc

I know there are probably many posts about this, but either I can't find the ones I need or my terminal just hates me. I'm trying to color coat the output of ls with the zsh shell on iterm2 on OSX.

I've tried using the alias "`alias ls='ls -laGH'`" and many variations but that has not worked.

I've tried using the LS_COLORS in zshrc with many variations but has not succeeded.

I've tried for hours to install this https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS with no success(and installed the zplugin of course).

My prediction that nothing has worked due to colors or themes that are already implemented but are taking precedence over the alias or GitHub repo?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is current .zshrc:

```
# Load Nerd Fonts with Powerlevel9k theme for Zsh
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='nerdfont-complete'
source ~/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme

# Customise the Powerlevel9k prompts
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(ssh dir vcs newline status)
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(time ram dir_writable)
POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE=true

# Load Zsh tools for syntax highlighting and autosuggestions
HOMEBREW_FOLDER="/usr/local/share"
source "$HOMEBREW_FOLDER/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh"

# Colorise the top Tabs of Iterm2 with the same color as background
# Just change the 18/26/33 which are the rgb values

echo -ne "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;18\a"
echo -ne "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;26\a"
echo -ne "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;33\a"

# Aliases for list commands with colorful output
alias ls='ls -laGH'
alias add='git add * ; git status'

source '/Users/christianquinn/.zplugin/plugins/trapd00r---LS_COLORS/c.zsh'
source "$HOMEBREW_FOLDER/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh"

### Added by Zplugin's installer
source '/Users/christianquinn/.zplugin/bin/zplugin.zsh'
autoload -Uz _zplugin
(( ${+_comps} )) && _comps[zplugin]=_zplugin
### End of Zplugin's installer chunk
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable to colorize output of `ls` change depend on the operating system in use.

On macOS (or on BSD based systems) you've to configure `LSCOLORS` variable, Like

```sh
  export LSCOLORS="Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacab"
```

In case of GNU, configure `LS_COLORS` variable

```sh
  export LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=41;33;01:ex=00;32:ow=0;41:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=01;32:*.com=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.dll=01;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tbz=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.deb=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.lzma=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.zoo=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.tb2=00;31:*.tz2=00;31:*.tbz2=00;31:*.avi=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.aiff=00;32:*.au=00;32:*.mid=00;32:*.mp3=00;32:*.ogg=00;32:*.voc=00;32:*.wav=00;32:*.patch=00;34:*.o=00;32:*.so=01;35:*.ko=01;31:*.la=00;33'
```

There are custom color generators like [geoff.greer.fm/lscolors](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors) that help in fine tuning the desired colors. Though plugins like [trapd00r/LS_COLORS](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS) provide colors for much larger set of file types.